# Retrieve HTTP Status Code from error Event in JQuery 3 image

Tags: jquery

I load an image by JQuery, but starting from JQuery 3 error() function was removed.
Now for error processing **on('error', ...)** should be used.

I need to know http error code for error processing. But can't find it in the event

```
var cur = $("<img class='img-test' src='...'/>").on('load', function() {
        ....
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        //get http status code there.... 
    })
```

I don't seem able to tell whether the error was a 500 or a 404. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Probably need to make a more formal request using ajax in error handler to get details

Comment: I prefer to avoid extra http calls because of performance reasons

Comment: Don't think you have a choice if you need the status

Comment: In the worst case I will hack jquery code =)

Comment: The original event object is provided by the browser. Issue has nothing to do with jQuery